# R read csv files with for loop with adding values

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, tidyverse

So i need help with a project i am currently doing. What i want to do is reading 90 csv files in a loop.

In this loop there are also two functions.
The function "Einsatzaufkommen" takes the unique amount of values of a column from the csv file.
The Function "Einsatzfahrtaufkommen" takes the total length of the same column.

The result of these 2 functions will add a value into another dataframe(variable name is bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen).
In this dataframe i have 3 columns and 90 rows("ID", "Einsatzaufkommen" and "Einsatzfahrtaufkommen").

The ID column will always match one of the values in the ID column (column name is ERHEBUNGSSTELLE) of the 90 csv files. The columns Einsatzfahrt and Einsatzfahrtaufkommen are currently empty because there is where i want to add the values.

So after reading each of the 90 csv files and applying the 2 functions i will add one value to column Einsatzaufkommen and Einsatzfahrtaufkommen at the row where the ID matches.
So the aim at the end is to fill up all 90 rows at these 2 columns
This is the code i have for now:

```
# This is the dataframe where i want to add all the values(in columns "Einsatzfahrt" and "Einsatzaufkommen")
bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen <- read_csv2("/Users/pablotrutnau/aktenschrank/Datenbericht/BASt/212-744 Einzelberichte - Beispielordner/BAST_Leistungsanalyse-Ansprechpartner_Erhebungsstellen.csv",
                                                   col_types = "c")

# directory of all the 90 csv files
verzeichnis <- "/Users/pablotrutnau/aktenschrank/Datenbericht/BASt/212-744 Einzelberichte - Beispielordner/Einsatzdaten"

# All csv files in the directory 
datensätze <- list.files(path = verzeichnis, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)

# start of loop 
for (daten in datensätze){
  # Reading the csv files
  datensatz <- read_csv2(daten, col_types = "c")

# "datensatz" is being renamed to "daten_gefiltert" after applying a function that filters some data of "datensatz" 

# Einsatz- und Einsatzfahrtaufkommen ######################################
  # Function that adds value to bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen(to column Einsatzaufkommen) 
  einsatzaufkommen <- function(){
    einsätze = round(length(unique(daten_gefiltert$E_NR)), digits = 0)
    # Matches between the IDs
    join_id <- match(bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen$ID, daten_gefiltert$ERHEBUNGSSTELLE)
    # Value is being added to bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen at the row where the id matches
    bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen$Einsatzaufkommen <- ifelse(!is.na(join_id), einsätze, NA)
    return(bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen)
  }
  
  # Function that adds value to dbast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen(to column Einsatzfahrtaufkommen)   
  einsatzfahrtaufkommen <- function(){
    fahrten = length(daten_gefiltert$E_NR)
    # Matches between the IDs
    join_id <- match(bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen$ID, daten_gefiltert$ERHEBUNGSSTELLE)
    # Value is being added to bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen at the row where the id matches
    bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen$Einsatzfahrtaufkommen <- ifelse(!is.na(join_id), fahrten, NA)
    return(bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen)
  }

# values are being added to bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen
  bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen <- einsatzaufkommen()
  bast_ansprechpartner_erhebungsstellen <- einsatzfahrtaufkommen()
}
```

Comment: Hello Pablo. Please read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. You need to include a small amount of data (e.g. subsets of 2 or 3 files) so someone can answer your question.

Comment: How big are these files?

Comment: Could you also add a little description about what your functions do? I suspect there is an easy way to do this, but its very difficult to understant your code

Comment: Also, I notice that the data frame `datensatz` is not referenced in either function. Since you're using a `for()` loop to process the files, and each loop appears to generate an update to one row in the ID data frame, there's likely a vector versus scalar problem in the two functions in the `match()` function.

Comment: I updated the Question trying to clear up some confusions adding details and deleting some parts of the code which are irrelevant for the problem

Answer (score 0):

Absent a minimal reproducible example it's not easy to replicate the original post. Therefore, we'll do our best to develop a solution by using data files for the 9 generations of Pokémon.

We  illustrate how to count the number of unique Pokémon IDs from each file, and merge them with another file that contains a set of generation identifiers so the final output has one row of data for each row in the generation identifier data frame.

This is a Base R solution that does not require additional packages.

First, we'll download a zip file containing the nine generations of Pokémon from a GitHub repository, and `unzip()` the file to extract the nine CSV files that are contained within it.

```
# download and extract files 
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/pokemonData.zip",
              "pokemonData.zip",
              method="curl",mode="wb")
unzip("pokemonData.zip")
```

We use `list.files()` to create a vector containing the full path names of the files we need to read from disk.

```
thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",
                              full.names=TRUE)
```

Next, to simulate the ID merge from the original post, we'll create a data frame of generation ID values where some of the IDs in this file match data we've downloaded, and at least one does not.

```
# create a data frame consisting of generation IDs to join
# containing at least one Pokémon generation that is not in the raw data
idData <- data.frame(genId = c("gen01","gen02","gen05","gen10"))
```

Here we use `lapply()` with an anonymous function to read each file, calculate the number of unique National Pokédex numbers in each file. To illustrate that there are some files where the same Pokémon is in the file more than one we will also calculate the total number of rows in each data file.

We convert the calculated objects into a data frame and return that from the anonymous function, so when `lapply()` is complete, it is a list of data frames.

```
pokemonDataFiles <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) {
     y <- read.csv(x,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
     # create the ID field from the file name parameter
     genId <- substr(x,15,19)
     uniquePokemon <- length(unique(y$ID)) 
     rowsInFile <- nrow(y)
     data.frame(genId,uniquePokemon,rowsInFile)
})
```

Here we use `do.call()` to combine the data frames into a single data frame so we can then use `merge()` to merge the results with the `idData` data frame.

```
# bind into 1 file 
results <- do.call(rbind,pokemonDataFiles)
```

Print the file to show that it has 9 rows, and that there are fewer unique IDs in some of the files. For example, the generation 3 file contains 4 forms of Castform and 4 forms of Deoxys, so the file should have 6 fewer unique IDs than rows in the file.

```
# print the merged data
results

> results
  genId uniquePokemon rowsInFile
1 gen01           151        151
2 gen02           100        100
3 gen03           135        141
4 gen04           107        118
5 gen05           156        165
6 gen06           119        131
7 gen07           110        122
8 gen08           134        147
9 gen09           105        115
```

Finally, we merge the two data frames and specify the `all.x = TRUE` argument so that all rows from the `idData` data frame are included in the output, and rows from `results` that do not match the `genId` field in `idData` are discarded.

```
# merge results so all rows from idData are included
merge(idData,results,all.x = TRUE)
```

...and the output:

```
> merge(idData,results,all.x = TRUE)
  genId uniquePokemon rowsInFile
1 gen01           151        151
2 gen02           100        100
3 gen05           156        165
4 gen10            NA         NA
```